# Centrar boton en IONIC

Tags: css, css3, ionic

Resulta que quiero centrar este botón:

```
<div class="">
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="facebookLogin()" style="width:300px;">
        <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
        &nbsp;Continuar con facebook
    </button>
</div>
```

y he intentado de varias maneras pero no consigo centrarlo.

¿Cómo podría centrar el botón dentro del `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que funcionará de la misma manera que en CSS normal. Puedes usar `text-align: center` para ello. En este caso he añadido al `div` que lo engloba una clase `centrado` para darle más contexto y que sea relevante pero le puedes poner un nombre cualquiera.

```css
.centrado{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centrado">
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="facebookLogin()" style="width:300px;">
        <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
        &nbsp;Continuar con facebook
    </button>
  </div>
```

---

Al ver que con los comentarios el problema era la clase `button-block` he investigado un poco sobre ella y tal y como pone en la **[documentación de Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#block-buttons)** cuando indicas la clase `button-block` a un botón este toma la propiedad `display: block;`, es decir, es considerado como un bloque.

Es por eso por lo que con la propiedad `text-align: center` el botón no se estaba centrando, porque la propiedad `text-align: center` solo afecta a elementos `inline` o elementos `inline-block`.

El botón es un elemento `inline` por defecto, y en condiciones normales debería de bastar usando `text-align: center` en su contenedor. Sin embargo, como en este caso le estabamos indicando que se comportase como un bloque esta propiedad no estaba realizando ningún efecto.

Como muy bien has dicho, quitando esta propiedad el botón va a ser centrado. ¿Por qué? Porque el botón volverá a su estado por defecto, en el cual es considerado como un elemento `inline` y por tanto si que le afectará la propiedad `text-align: center`.

Comment: no me quiere funcionar... nose que sera!

Comment: @HernanHumaña ¿Tienes algo de código adicional? ¿Cómo le insertas el CSS?

Comment: es un proyecto nuevo generado con ionic, tenia una clase padding que sí la saque para descartar y aún nada.

Comment: @HernanHumaña Acabo de ver que existe una clase que se llama `text-center`. Prueba sustituyendo eso por la clase `centrado`.

Comment: lo intente mucho y aún nada.

Comment: ya lo solucione, quite la clase button-block que venia incorporada en ionic.

Comment: @HernanHumaña Publica una respuesta nueva con tu solución! :D

Comment: @HernanHumaña He añadido una explicación de porque quitando esa clase la propiedad `text-align: center` vuelve a funcionar.